# UWP. Is changing .appxmanifest triggers local app data to be removed?

Tags: windows, uwp

I want to update my application declarations (add some new) in .appxmanifest file. Also, my application has sensible data in LocalState folder, so it cannot be lost.

The question is if I add these declarations (change .appxmanifest file) will it trigger the application reinstall and as a result data loss in LocalState folder?

I found in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) and [Q&A](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/06/19/common-questions-and-answers-about-files-and-app-data-part-1-app-data/#0Z5DhQCuOzKO2zJI.97) that changes to AppManifest can trigger app reinstall but there are no details which changes exactly will bring me to this situation.

Comment: Interesting. I don't have the answer, but If you have the uwp app on the store, you can evaluate it with package flight. With package flight, you can evaluate the behavior of updating the package with capability change from store with isolated - not public - environment.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-flights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change this file locally and then rebuild the project the app will be reinstalled when debugging.

Changes like these won't cause a reinstall when updates are distributed through the store.

Comment: Thank you for help. However, I added few declarations in AppManifest and it wasn't reinstalled when I launched it in Debug nor in Release mode. All data and settings are fine.